# How to maintain security in folder or for any files?

Tags: php

I have been working on a project and using `php` as programming language. My project is a website which is almost completed but I have an issue regarding security of certain folders which should not be accessible to all public but my website should be able to use the resource inside the folder properly. The resource could be anything inside the folder basically some text files, pictures and scripts. Can anyone give me basic idea to deal with the problem?

Also to be noted that I cannot add some bunch of `php` code or any code to each of the files.

Comment: The key to your problem most probably is `.htaccess`. You will find a lot of resources and answers around the web.

Comment: What do you mean by "my website should be able to use the resource inside the folder". What is in this folder anyway? If you have images, JS, CSS, downloadable files, or anything directly embedded in the page's source - this is impossible. There are some techniques against hot-linking, though. If there's only data files read by your site's code, then it is possible using `.htaccess`to deny access to this folder.

Comment: Unless it contains files that the web page uses (js/css/images etc), and only files that are read by your PHP code (config files etc.), you should keep them outside of the public folder completely.